# Open a web page in the browser using flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Am using this AS 2.0 Code on a button in flash CS3 :
on(press, release) {
getURL("http://somethinghere...","_top");
}

unfortunately, it doesnt work.

However, when i Ctrl+Enter in flash and click the button, it does.

it doesnt work after embedding the SWF movie in the webpage/browser.
any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, try to use "_blank"? And maybe the popup blocker kicked in?

Comment: i have already tried _blank _top and _self, 
no luck though ..
nothing says that popup blocked, and am having this problem on different computers

Comment: Actually, _blank did work , 
but neither of _top or _self worked :s this is strange.

also, when using _blank, it actually opened 3 browser windows instead of one, strange..

Comment: Seems like a situation that needs a deep breath and checking some plugs. :)

Answer (score 0):

is the the Flash player vs the browsers player?

I've experienced to have 3 different versions of Flashplayer running while developing.

I dont have CS3 anymore, so I cant reproduce your problem I am afraid, but check if you might have more than one version of the player installed (there might be an old one in your CS3 folders)

Secondly, what happens if you embed it in a HTML file? is it the same experience on harddrive as online?